# Detect if device is touch enabled and below a certain screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to activate/disable :hover depending on device, and I guess the best way is to check if the device is touch enabled and also detect the screen size, because of the newest laptops which also have touch screens. Is there a way to do this with javascript/jquery?

Comment: there are already quite some answers to these questions available on SO...

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Another way to detect as follows:

```
function is_touch_device() {
  return !!('ontouchstart' in window);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option, Modernizr will be able to detect touch (in addition to a bunch of other properties of the target browser/device): http://modernizr.com/ It will put an appropriate class on the html tag, which you can detect.

To detect screen size (oh well, browser window size), you can use this:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

Comment: More FYI, but Modernizr doesn't detect touch devices, just touch events: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/548

Answer (score 0):

```
var touchDevice = (typeof (window.ontouchstart) !== 'undefined') ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) and media queries :

On the modernizr's download page you create a file with TOUCH EVENT **checked**.
Modernizr will include a `touch` or `no-touch` class on your `<body>`

In your CSS for each `:hover` insert before a `.no-touch`.
In the next sample, only screens with a width higher than 768px and without touch events will have an `:hover`.

```
/* CSS */
a{
    color:#DD0000; /* Dark red */
    text-decoration:none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .no-touch a:hover {
        color:#FF0000; /* red */
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
}
```